# Is this where all the iOS developers are?

Tags: discussion, ios

I'm new to all of this. I just recently made a stack overflow account and came across StackExchange. So I guess this site is made up of other communities with similar interest? Is this where I can find the iOS developers. I'm just getting started in iOS development. Other than what I learned from watching youtube videos, I'm brand new to it.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to Ask Different! This Stack Exchange community primarily address Q&A around use of Apple Hardware, Software and Services.

You may find some iOS developers here, but this is not the place to ask iOS development (specifically code level or API) related questions. However some questions are allowed on this site, which an iOS developer may have (like, how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks). iOS development related questions are on-topic on another sister site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

For various other questions that you may have while using Apple hardware, software and services, you are welcome to post your question on the [Ask Different Site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). This question has been migrated to [Ask Different Meta Site](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/) which answers question about the Ask Different site.

You can go through this support article, [Help Center > Asking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to better understand what kind of questions are allowed on Ask Different.

Good luck with your iOS development journey!

Answer (score 7):

Developers use lots of Apple products and services so all of those questions are welcome and on-topic at Ask Different. The only items that are off-topic are code level questions like:

- What API is best to use for *whatever specific thing you will do*?
- What is causing this minimal, complete, verifiable example code to error?
- How can I learn to [code | discuss how to be a developer | market my apps]?

Welcome to the site and should you ask one or two questions off topic - they will get closed and you can ask here on meta again if they could be edited to be on scope or possibly find a home on a site more specific to the question you actually asked. Not having any question closed is best, but sometimes the [help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) isn’t super clear.